# Find type of image in clipboard

Tags: c#, image, clipboard

I have an image copied to the clicpboard from the word using "Comment.Scope.CopyAsPicture()"
How can i find the type of this image in the clipboard, so that i can write the image with proper extension in local file system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [DataFromats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats.aspx) we have only Bitmap member...

normally you choose the format to store

```
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if (data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
{
  Bitmap bitmap = (data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap,true) as Bitmap);

  bitmap.Save("image.bmp",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
  bitmap.Save("image.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

}
```

but You can create Your own format and use it

```
DataFormats.Format jepgFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat("jpgFormat");

Image image = new Image(); 
DataObject myDataObject = new DataObject(jpegFormat.Name, image );

// Copies myObject into the clipboard.
Clipboard.SetDataObject(myDataObject);
```

Comment: The `DataFormats` are just strings. There's no limits in what can be in there. That said, images on the clipboard as type Bitmap indeed have no real type; it's just an image object.

Answer (score 1):

Using DataFormats.Bitmap you can get this as a bitmap and use the framework functions to save it.

`if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))`
`Bitmap bImg = (Bitmap)iData.GetData();`